# Strange const definition with asm

Tags: android, c, gcc, build, native

I am trying to build [Ne10](https://github.com/projectNe10/Ne10) library for Android, cmake reports:

> -- Target architecture: armv7
>
> -- Building type: RELEASE
>
> -- Loaded toolchain:
>
> ```
> ../Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle//toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
>
> ../Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle//toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++
>
> ../Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle//toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-as
> ```
>
> -- CMAKE_C_FLAGS:
>
> -std=c11 -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -DNDEBUG --sysroot=/home/gica/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle//platforms/android-21/arch-arm/ -pie -mthumb-interwork -mthumb -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfp3 -Wl,--no-warn-mismatch

but compiler reports this error:

> In file included from ...Ne10/common/NE10_mask_table.c:32:0:
>   ..Ne10/common/NE10_mask_table.h:41:65:
>
> error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before 'asm'
>
> extern const ne10_uint32_t ne10_qMaskTable32[Q_MASK_TABLE_SIZE] asm ("ne10_qMaskTable32");

in header "NE10_mask_table.h" there is those strange definitions:

```
#include "NE10_types.h"
#ifndef _ARM_MASK_TABLE_H
#define _ARM_MASK_TABLE_H

#define Q_MASK_TABLE_SIZE        20
#define D_MASK_TABLE_SIZE        6
#define DIV_LOOKUP_TABLE_SIZE    255

/* mask table for dsp module */
extern const ne10_uint32_t ne10_qMaskTable32[Q_MASK_TABLE_SIZE] asm ("ne10_qMaskTable32");
extern const ne10_uint32_t ne10_dMaskTable32[D_MASK_TABLE_SIZE] asm ("ne10_dMaskTable32");
```

I am confused with "expected 'asm' before 'asm'

What am I missing?

Comment: The "strange definitions" are using gcc's [asm labels](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Asm-Labels.html) to give a specific assembler name to the associated C variables rather than using the C default naming scheme.  At a guess, the compiler error comes from not finding a definition for `ne10_uint32_t`.

Comment: No it is not that, but thank you for hint about asm labels. `ne10_uint32-t` is `typedef unsigned int` in **"NE10_types.h"**. It seems that compiler has problem with asm labels, I get same error on simple `int foo asm ("myfoo") = 2;`.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that you do not have an `#endif` associated with the `#ifndef`

Comment: Oh, sorry I mistyped there is space between asm and '(..'

Answer (score 0):

Ah, there it is: [asm keyword](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Alternate-Keywords.html#Alternate-Keywords) it is now clear, compiler accepts `__asm__` not `asm`. It is all clear now.